# Binary numbers instead of one hot vectors

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

While doing logistic regression, it is common practice to use one-hot vectors as desired result. So, `no of classes = no of nodes in output layer`. We don't use index of word in vocabulary because that may falsely indicate closeness of two classes. But why can't we use binary numbers instead of one-hot vectors?

i.e if there are 4 classes, we can represent each class as 00,01,10,11 resulting in `log(no of classes)` nodes in output layer.

Comment: I am not sure what  hot vector is. Can you provide a link?

Comment: @Carl  one hot vector = all elements 0 except one element that is 1. E.g. 000000100

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using binary numbers instead of one-hot vectors introduces dependencies between the different classes.

For example, if

```
number: class name
00: blue
01: red
10: black
11: green
```

then the first bit should be 0 whenever it is blue or red. This may confuse the classifier.

However, the approach can sometimes be useful, e.g. see [hierarchical output layer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B95LTf2rVWM) where the choice of the tree can significantly impact the performance of the network.

[image]

{1} report the following though:

> The table shows that Negative Sampling outperforms the Hierarchical Softmax on the analogical
>   reasoning task, and has even slightly better performance than the Noise Contrastive Estimation.

so you may want to explore methods other than hierarchical softmax when doing speed optimization.

---

- {1} Mikolov, Tomas, Ilya Sutskever, Kai Chen, Greg S. Corrado, and Jeff Dean. "Distributed representations of words and phrases and their compositionality." In Advances in neural information processing systems, pp. 3111-3119. 2013. http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5021-distributed-representations-of-words-and-phrases-and-their-compositionality.pdf ; https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=2410615501856807729&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Franck, there are tradeoffs for sure. In some cases where the categorical variable has a very large number of categories, one hot encoding can blow out the dataset, which also isn't great for some classifiers/datasets. So in those cases, pragmatically, trading off some encoding quality for a smaller dataset can make some sense.

If you want to experiment with it, you can use the BaseN encoder in https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/categorical-encoding. It lets you specify a base (base-1 is taken to be equivalent to one-hot, base-2 is the binary case, etc.), and then you can do a grid search or something like that to find a base that works out. But, if you can get away with it, one-hot is going to represent the categories more correctly always.